# Gnome keyring doesn't unlock after loging in using Pam-face-authentication

Tags: login, gnome-keyring

I am using http://pam-face-authentication.org/ to log into my system using face detection and it is working just great except for one thing,The authentication runs out of the box, but it doesn't unlock my keyring.

So after loging into my system, I see my desktop and everything normally but then a password prompt pops-up asking for Gnome-keyring, I think if it can log me into the system just fine then it should also be able to unlock the gnome-kerying.

This guy also have the same issue -->
https://bugs.launchpad.net/gdm/+bug/479881/comments/4

Answer (score 2):

That is because your keyring is encrypted with your login password, and since you don't enter the password to log in, pam can not unlock your keyring automatically.  There may be a way to disable the keyring password, but I am not sure how.  Of course, this would mean that if your system is compromised, someone could read all of your passwords and keys stored in the keyring.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your keyring password to be an empty password... **be aware your passwords will no longer be encrypted**

System -> Preferences -> Encryption and Keyrings

Right click on "Passwords : login" and select change password

Enter nothing in the new password boxs

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that some applications get a tad annoyed if there's no password on the default keyring, so instead you could use a script to unlock it with a password. See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1159096